# Limit checkbox based on condition

Tags: javascript

Hi need help from expert as I'm totally newcomers.
I'm trying to limit checkbox based on condition.
As for example, if bank code from user selection is `MBS` they able to select only 3 checkbox, while if bank code is `MBV` they able to select only five.
Below are the codes that i'm trying to work with.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
        function checkboxlimit(bankcode, checkgroup, limit) {
            var bankcode = document.frmSearch.bank_code
            var checkgroup = checkgroup
            var limit = limit
            for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++) {
                checkgroup[i].onclick = function () {
                    var checkedcount = 0
                    for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++)
                        checkedcount += (checkgroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0
                    if (bankcode == 'MBS')
                        if (checkedcount > limit) {
                            alert("You can only select a maximum of " + limit + " checkboxes")
                            this.checked = false
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    </script>

    <form id = "status"
          name = "status" >
        <input type = "checkbox"
               name = "check" /> london <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox"
               name = "check"/> japan <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox"
               name = "check"/> usa <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox"
               name = "check"/> korea <br/>
        <input type = "checkbox"
               name = "check"/> egypt <br/>
    </form>

    <script type = "text/javascript" >
        checkboxlimit(document.frmSearch.bank_code, document.forms.status.check, 2) 
    </script>
```

Comment: can you share html or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable to keep track of how many elements are checked. This variable can be updated using the `onchange`event on the checkbox.
[Here a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj58hw3e/39/) with a complete working example.

**Bonus**

You can disable the unchecked boxes when the limit is reached, so that the user cannot check more boxes than allowed.
See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gL9p2svc/5/).

Comment: Its working! Thanks a lot.. I have one more issue to be solved regarding this checkbox. If there is one checkbox to select all the checkbox option based on the bank code limit. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, it is possible. You need to set a function on the `onchange` event of the new checkbox. This function performs a `for` loop that sets the `checked` option on the other checkbox, very similar to the code I posted.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.I'm struggling to make the checkbox to be automate checked based on the bank code selection. Need your favor again.

Comment: As I said, it is a minor modification of the code I sent. If you have issues, open another question, showing what you tried and why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd go about it using jQuery assuming there are only two types of bankcodes (MBV and MBS)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkboxlimit(bankcode) {
        var limit =  bankcode === "MBS" ? 3 : 5;
        $(':checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
            if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
                this.checked = false;
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<form id="status" name="status">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"/>london<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"/>japan<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"/>usa<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"/>korea<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"/>egypt<br/>
</form>

<script typ="text/javascript">
    checkboxlimit(document.frmSearch.bank_code) 
</script>
```

*PS : I have no idea what this (**document.frmSearch**) does as the code snippet is unclear regarding its function, but I choose to keep it since you provided it in the original code.*